# How To Resolve The Error Of Payment method while billing for setting up an account on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, billing

I am facing issue while setting up my account on google cloud platform. i want to set up an account and when I got into step 3 i.e Step of Billing process after completing the whole process when I click to start my free trial. It showing "**An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again later. [OR-CRMMT-01]**" dialogue. How can this get fixed?

Comment: Wait and try again later. Do the typical things like reboot your computer, clear the browser cache, use a different browser, etc. Your question has few details, so we can only guess. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

The above error is due to your banking payment method. Certain countries only allow a few banks' credit or debit cards for automatic payments. If your card or bank is not on the list, make a manual or pre-pay account.
Workaround for this issue is to use a supported banking card as a primary payment method and then use the other company card from where you want to pay

Comment: I have the same error. Also I tried 3 times and each time 2 rupees debited from my account. So, If they are not accepting the card then how come the transaction is getting done. I have Paytm Virtual VISA card.

Comment: Have you found any solution yet?

Comment: @D_Gamer same thing happened to me, i also have Paytm visa card & ₹2 debited from my account 4 times have you found any solution?

Comment: No I haven't found any solution yet, but I think the problem is with our Payment method; I think Paytm VISA card won;t work ( Well atleast for Google Cloud Platform ; 'coz I already have verified my account on DIgital Ocean using the same Paytm VISA card). So if anyone have a proper Credit Card, they can give it a try and if it works please reply to this message.

Answer (score 0):

You may have multiple options for what profile of your you're linking as well.  I finally noticed that I had two profiles, one was for donations, one was already linked to Google Play.  I switched to the one with Google Play and was able to complete the setup